# secured or encrypted push notification messages from MobileFirst server

Tags: encryption, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing an Banking Mobile application using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 which should be much secured.

I implemented the normal IBM MobileFirst push notification in our application. Now client requirement is that to send some secured information to the customer as notification, hence want to send secured or encrypted push notification messages to the mobile client from MobileFirst server through GCM or APNS.

Is there any built-in MobileFirst API available to fulfill the requirement?

Answer (score 2):

GCM and APNS push notifications are encrypted in transit using TLS, but the MobileFirst Platform doesn't provide an API to do end-to-end encryption of push notifications (i.e., to encrypt the actual notification payload, which would then need to be decrypted by the app).

If you wish to have this type of functionality in your application, you would need to implement the payload encryption/decryption yourself, using whatever type of encryption meets your needs.

If you think the product should provide an API to do this type of function, you should open a [Request For Enhancement](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe) describing what you would suggest that the product should do, and your use case, so that the product managers can consider it.