# encrypted push notification messages to be pushed from MobileFirst server to mobile

Tags: encryption, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing an Banking Mobile application using MobileFirst V7.1 which should be much secured. I implemented the normal IBM MobileFirst push notification in our application.

Following are the requirements from the client:

1) To send some sensitive information to the customer as notification, hence want to send secured or encrypted push notification messages to the mobile client from MobileFirst server through GCM or APNS. Is there any built-in Worklight/MobileFirst  API available to fullfill the requiremnt,  Can anyone please help me in suggesting some solution to fullfill this requirement. It will be very greatful if some one give me solutions for this.

2) Also Client requirement is to send platform specific notification, some push notification to be send only to Iphone and some specific notification only to Android devices. Is there any option in the SubmitNotification() method to send platform specific push notifications.

3) Currenly we are providing a url "http://IPAddress:8080/invoke?adapter=ADAPTER_NAME&procedure=PROCEDURE_NAME&parameters=[PARAMETER1,PAREMETER2,...]" to the web service team to hit this URL to send the push notifications. Currently this URL is public any anyone who knows the URL can execute or hit the URL and send the notification. I need to protect this URL where no unknown resource or unauthorised person should access the URL. If some tries to hit/access the URL, it should ask for the credentials and the URL should be secured as we are dealing with Banking application everything should be secured hence the push notification URL should be secure. Can anyone please tell me how to implement this.

Thanks in advance
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Your first question has already been previously answered; don't duplicate your own questions: [secured or encrypted push notification messages from MobileFirst server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014798/secured-or-encrypted-push-notification-messages-from-mobilefirst-server)

For your second question, send separate notifications. Once for APNS and once for GCM... and you should use the `submitMessage` API instead. See here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html#sendMessage

Your third question should be directed at your own IT Security team, because this is something that *you* need to do in *your organization*. Your IT team should know how to protect internal resources with your firewall settings, to not allow incoming connections from the public internet, but only internal connections from your organization network.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your reply Idan Adar